# TS : Generic parameter defaults with key mapping

Tags: typescript, generics, default-value

I try to constrain function parameters :

```
interface MyList {
  color: string
  static: boolean
  ...
}

create <T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> (arg: [K, V]) {}
```

But the call look like

```
create<MyList, 'color', string>(['color', 'red'])
```

So I tried with default generic types :

```
create <T, K extends keyof T = keyof T, V extends T[K] = T[K]> (arg: [K, V]) {}
create<MyList>(['color', false]) // <- no error because ['color|static', 'string|boolean']
```

But it didn't work anymore.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have a list of value/type in a interface. The first argument of the function must be a key of that list and and the second parameter is the type related to that key. I try to limit the redondancy of the first example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your second approach is that if you specify the value for the type parameter, no inference will occur for that parameter, so K will be the union of all keys `color | static | ...` and so `T[K]` will be a union of all property types.

You could do the following :

```
function create <T, K  extends keyof T> (arg: [K, T[K]]) {}

create<MyList, 'color'>(['color', ''])
create<MyList, 'color'>(['color', true]) //error
```

It's still a bit verbose, but you don't need to specify the property type, that will be correctly typed.

Or you could use a two function approach to lock in `T` first and let the compiler infer `K`

```
function create <T>() {
    return function <K  extends keyof T> (arg: [K, T[K]]) {

    }
} 

create<MyList>()(['color', ''])
create<MyList>()(['color', true]) //error
```

Or if `create` is a member of a generic class then this problem goes away:

```
class Creator<T> {
    create<K extends keyof T>(arg: [K, T[K]]) {

    }
}
let creator = new Creator<MyList>();
creator.create(['color', ''])
creator.create(['color', true]) //error
```

**Edit**

As discussed in the comments you want to take an arbitrary number of key/value pairs and have them correctly checked. You can't do this for an arbitrary number of arguments, but you can define overloads for up to n pairs, for example 3. If you call with more you will get an error so you will know it's time to add more overloads:

```
class Creator<T> {
    create<K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T, K3 extends keyof T>(arg1: [K1, T[K1]], arg2: [K2, T[K2]], arg3: [K3, T[K3]]): void
    create<K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T>(arg1: [K1, T[K1]], arg2: [K2, T[K2]]): void
    create<K1 extends keyof T>(arg: [K1, T[K1]]): void
    // Implementation sigature, not directly callable 
    create<K extends keyof T>(...arg: [K, T[K]][]) {

    }
}
let creator = new Creator<MyList>();
creator.create(['color', ''])
//Works for up to 3 items
creator.create(['color', ''], ['color', ''], ['color', '']) 
// Is an error if there are more so you will know to add more overloads
creator.create(['color', ''], ['color', ''], ['color', ''], ['color', ''])
```

Comment: Thanks ! The 'create' method is indeed a method and your last solution was my starting point. My goal is to allows that method accepts an arbitrary number of arguments like this : (...args: Array<[K, T[K]]>) but in this case also, it has no inferrence. I need to define the type inside the function I think. Something like (...args: Type<T>[])

Comment: @Tiramitsu That is a different beast :) You can't do that without a separate type parameter for each key. You can define several overloads, but it will work for a set number of arguments, not for any number of arguments. I'll add the code

Comment: @Tiramitsu added an overloaded version

Comment: I effectively doubted about the spread operator since it introduce some dynamic behaviors that typescript can't predict. Your overload version fits to me perfectly. still verbose but since its in the declaration, Its not a bit of a problem ! Thanks you Titian !